# CFURL does not give full data when download

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, core-foundation

Iam trying to use CFHTTP to write a small downloader. Unfortunately I cannot use NSURL which is very easy. I basically want an async way to download the data and store it in a file. I have not yet found how to do async way but I have some code with Sync approach which not working as well. The problem is the downloader does not download the complete bytes. I see some data missing causing the final file to be corrupt. Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
#include <CFNetwork/CFHTTPStream.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    const char *data;
    FILE *fp;
    CFShow(CFSTR("Hello, World!\n"));

    CFURLRef cfUrl = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/x86/putty.zip"), NULL);
    CFHTTPMessageRef cfHttpReq = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("GET"), cfUrl, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);

    CFReadStreamRef readStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfHttpReq);
    CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);

    CFHTTPMessageRef cfHttpResp = CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty(kCFAllocatorDefault, TRUE);
    CFIndex numBytesRead;

    do {
        const int nBuffSize = 1024;
        UInt8 buff[nBuffSize];
        numBytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(readStream, buff, nBuffSize);
        if( numBytesRead > 0 )
        {
            CFHTTPMessageAppendBytes(cfHttpResp, buff, numBytesRead);
        }
        else if( numBytesRead < 0 )
        {
            CFStreamError error = CFReadStreamGetError(readStream);
            printf ("Error %d", error.error);
        }
    } while ( numBytesRead > 0 );
    CFStringRef myStatusLine = CFHTTPMessageCopyResponseStatusLine(cfHttpReq);
    CFReadStreamClose(readStream);
    CFDataRef cfResp = CFHTTPMessageCopyBody(cfHttpResp);
    CFIndex length = CFDataGetLength(cfResp);
    printf ("%lu\n", length);
    CFShow(myStatusLine);
    data = (const char*)CFDataGetBytePtr(cfResp);
    fp = fopen("/var/tmp/Update.zip", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ACnnot be opened\n");
    } else {
        fwrite(data, length, 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf ("Download done\n");
    CFRelease(cfUrl);
    CFRelease(cfHttpReq);
    CFRelease(readStream);
    CFRelease(cfHttpResp);
    CFRelease(cfResp);

    return 0;
}
```

The length I get is less than my actual file download. I dont understand whats is wrong with this code. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you try debugging.

Comment: It looks like Iam getting numBytesRead to be 0 which breaks the loop. But my file is not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still dont know what went wrong in this code. But I fixed my problem by replacing

//CFHTTPMessageRef cfHttpResp = CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty(kCFAllocatorDefault, TRUE);
    CFMutableDataRef cfResp = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
I now use MutableDataRef instead of CFHTTPMessageRef. I will upadte the new code here.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    const char *data;
    FILE *fp;
    CFShow(CFSTR("Hello, World!\n"));

    CFURLRef cfUrl = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/x86/putty.zip"), NULL);
    CFHTTPMessageRef cfHttpReq = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("GET"), cfUrl, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);

    CFReadStreamRef readStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfHttpReq);
    CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);

    //CFHTTPMessageRef cfHttpResp = CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty(kCFAllocatorDefault, TRUE);
    CFMutableDataRef cfResp = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CFIndex numBytesRead;

    do {
        const int nBuffSize = 1024;
        UInt8 buff[nBuffSize];
        numBytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(readStream, buff, nBuffSize);
        if( numBytesRead > 0 )
        {
            CFDataAppendBytes(cfResp, buff, numBytesRead);
            //CFHTTPMessageAppendBytes(cfHttpResp, buff, numBytesRead);
        }
        else if( numBytesRead < 0 )
        {
            CFStreamError error = CFReadStreamGetError(readStream);
            printf ("Error %d", error.error);
        }
    } while ( numBytesRead > 0 );

    CFReadStreamClose(readStream);
    //CFDataRef cfResp = CFHTTPMessageCopyBody(cfHttpResp);
    CFIndex length = CFDataGetLength(cfResp);
    printf ("%lu\n", length);

    data = (const char*)CFDataGetBytePtr(cfResp);
    fp = fopen("/var/tmp/Update.zip", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ACnnot be opened\n");
    } else {
        fwrite(data, length, 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf ("Download done\n");
    CFRelease(cfUrl);
    CFRelease(cfHttpReq);
    CFRelease(readStream);
    CFRelease(cfResp);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. It will still be useful if someone can point out what went wrong original code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this late, but your code really helped me out (it is surprisingly hard to find straight forward, complete, examples of getting the response body bytes using CFNetworking API).

Anyway, I think the mistake was the last parameter should be FALSE (response message), and not TRUE (request message) in CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty line.

```
CFHTTPMessageRef cfHttpResp = CFHTTPMessageCreateEmpty(kCFAllocatorDefault, FALSE);
```